# If I purchase DLC from Nintendo, can the child accounts linked to my account access it on the same device?

Tags: nintendo-switch, pokemon-sword-shield, nintendo-eshop

I bought my children a switch for Xmas, along with Pokémon Sword. I would like to purchase the DLC that is coming out this year, and wanted to know if they can access it from their accounts.

At the moment, they just change user when it’s their turn, they share pretty well, and I want to be sure they will share the DLC.

Their accounts are child accounts linked to my account

Answer (score 1):

My running understanding is that you will only need to purchase 1 expansion pass for your console, although we won't be able to be 100% sure until the DLC comes out (aside - if you pre-ordered it, does everyone get access to the bonus clothing?)

This seems to be the general assumption for the DLC as explained here: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/switch/259372-pokemon-sword/answers/533535-will-i-need-an-expansion-pass-for-both-accounts

> So based on the info on the eShop, it looks like this is just standard DLC. Which means that it should be accessible across all your consoles profiles so long as the account that purchased the content has that Switch set as it's primary console.
>
> So if your you bought the DLC, and your Nintendo Account has the Switch your playing on set as it's Primary Console, then any software you purchase including DLC will be accessible across all other users on that console.

Comment: Can confirm; purchasing the 1 expansion pack will let all the other accounts use it. Just make sure you purchase the DLC for Sword and not Shield